# Is there a way to tell Eclipse how to resolve ambiguous java names?

Tags: eclipse

My eclipse is configured so that when I save the java source file, it automatically inserts the missing import declarations. Except when the reference is ambiguous. Fpr instance, the most annoying ambiguity is with `List<T>` - both `java.util` and `java.awt` declare it. Here eclipse demands manual resolution.

I was wondering if it was possible to configure somewhere that whenever `List<T>` is used then `java.util` should be imported. Or alternatively, since I am not using `java.awt`, I could just remove it from the list of possible suggestions.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019698/exclude-packages-from-eclipses-organize-imports

Comment: Very similar indeed, missed that one.

Comment: @E-Riz - please, arrange your comment as an answer so I could credit  you for it, since it seems to be the closest thing to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a possible duplicate of [Exclude packages from Eclipse's organize imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019698/exclude-packages-from-eclipses-organize-imports).
Basically, you want to change your **Type Filters** preference to exclude `java.awt.*` packages. Keep in mind that doing so will make things harder/confusing if you ever try to write AWT/Swing code.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that pops into my mind is altering the class template in the preferences to include the line:

```
import java.util.List
```

Unless you are going to use the AWT version of a List, or care about unused import statements, that should solve this annoying issue ..

Answer (score 0):

Manually invoke Organize Imports and it will ask you when an ambiguity is found.

Comment: That is what I am doing now. I guess I am spoiled, but it is annoying.